# Excepting Specific web form from Google Login Authorisation using ASP.Net/Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, authorization, scheduled-tasks, azure-web-app-service

I'm running a asp.net c# web app in Azure and using Google Log In to authenticate. Using Azure I have scheduled one of my webforms to Get every hour to update a database.

The problem is that I can't enter Google authorisation credentials within Azure so it won't run in the scheduler.

Is there a way to exempt this single web form and keep authorisation on the rest?

I tied the following in Web.config, but it still the webform still redirects to google's login page.

```
<location path="QuickRefresh.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unsure how your entire app is configured so with that said, if you simply want to hit some "endpoint" (no ui/interface), then see if a generic handler `ashx` will do it for you. Code is a bit more "bare metal" HTTP if you need to get into details and/or add simple auth - e.g. `BASIC` (over SSL). Hth.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but I'm still running into the same issues. I'll just create a separate web app without any authentication, specifically for this task.